# Is there a less clumsy alternative for copying up to "n" array elements?

Tags: perl

> In a world of many `@choices`
>   With a `$limit` to what one can do,
>   Life proposes many `@options`
>   But at times just one or two.
>   In a bid to minimize line noise
>   What can [Tim Toady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) do?

Here are a few ways I've thought of, but they just seem so clumsy. Surely there's a more elegant way to DWIM:

- *Verbose one-liner*

  ```
  my @choices = @options <= $limit ? @options : @options[0..$limit-1];  # Blech
  ```
- *Slice control*

  ```
  my @choices = @options[0..(@options <= $limit ? $#options : $limit - 1)]; # Even worse
  ```
- *Cheesy slice inside a slice*

  ```
  my @choices = @options[0..($#options, $limit-1 )[@options > $limit]];  # Crazy eyes
  ```
- *Clearer intent, but over two lines*

  ```
  my @choices = @options;
     @choices = @options[0..$limit-1] if $limit < @options;
  ```

Comment: If you're looking for _clumsier_ alternatives, be sure to visit [codegolf.se]

Comment: In Perl 6 it would be `my @choices = @options[ ^( * min $limit ) ]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@choices = @options; splice @choices, $limit;  # "splice() offset past end" before v5.16
```

It can also be done in a single statement!

```
@choices = splice @{[@options]}, 0, $limit;
```

And also

```
splice @{$choices_ref=[@options]}, $limit;  # Warns "splice() offset past end" before v5.16
splice $choices_ref=[@options], $limit;     # Ditto. Requires Perl v5.14. "Experimental"
```

Comment: ... man, this solution is way better. The first statement is a copy, then splice works in place right?

Comment: Tragically, `splice @choices=@options,$limit` doesn't work

Comment: But `my @choices = splice ( @options, 0, $limit );` does.

Comment: This is not an exact answer, because the question was how to copy just a maximum number of elements. You copy all of them, before you throw away those you have copied unnecessarily. This might be a performance problem with big arrays.

Comment: @ceving - performance was not a concern here, I was just after something more elegant. The two-statement option was far better than my alternatives, but the one-liner is pure theatre. Hats off to mob, this one's a winner :)

Comment: `@choices = splice @{ sub{ \@_ }->( @options ) }, 0, $limit;` avoids copying the values of `@options` twice.

Answer (score 7):

```
my @choices = @options[0..min($#options, $limit-1)];
```

Short, straightforward, clear.

Comment: The `min` function requires [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html), because Perl has [no built-in](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=406883) function.

Comment: Weird that we have the same answer, yet I generated less votes :( I guess people really do prefer short(er) answers

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, There's more to presentation than just length. You buried your answer in a code snippet, so I didn't even see it. If you had simply added it to the top of your answer, it would have been a better answer. But worse, the OP wanted something a clear and elegant solution, and including a 24-line program yells the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

Of the options you provided I actually like #1 and #4 and have definitely written statements like those before. If those options *really* bothered me, I might write it this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(min);
use Data::Dumper;

my @options = ('a'..'c');
my $limit   = 5;

my @choices = @options[0..min($limit-1, $#options)];
print Dumper \@choices;
# $VAR1 = [
#      'a',
#      'b',
#      'c'
#    ];    

$limit = 2;
@choices = @options[0..min($limit-1, $#options)];
print Dumper \@choices;
# $VAR1 = [
#       'a',
#       'b'
#   ];
```

but this is largely opinion based and I am sure other people would do it differently.

Comment: This one is actually way better than anything I'd come up with. Expresses the intent far more clearly. That -1 is an eyesore :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
my @choices = splice ( @options, 0, $limit );
```

Note that `splice` acts like `shift`/`pop` and modifies the source array - if that's undesirable, then copy it first.

Comment: You have my +1... the caveat is important because the original array does get altered with this approach. Fixing that issue then leaves little difference between this answer and [mob's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39022313/133939).

Answer (score 0):

```
my @choices = first_x_ele($limit, @options);
```

If you think something is unclear, use a sub! How you implement the sub isn't very important, but a short one would be:

```
sub first_x_ele { my $x = shift; splice(@_, 0, $x) }
```