# How can I use coderefs instead literal subs when there is a `&` prototype?

Tags: perl, anonymous-function, plack

I'm trying to make [Router::Resource](http://p3rl.org/Router::Resource) work
where the parameters to the functions are not literal anonymous subs, but
coderefs defined earlier. I am doing this to curtail code duplication.

Here's the code from the synopsis in a minimal but working fashion. This works.

```
# app.psgi
use 5.024;
use Router::Resource qw(resource router GET POST);
my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    my $router = router {
        resource '/' => sub {
            GET { [200, [], ['get /']] };
        };
        resource '/blog/{year}/{month}' => sub {
            GET  { [200, [], ['get /blog']] };
            POST { [200, [], ['post /blog']] };
        };
    };
    $router->dispatch($env);
}
__END__
$ plackup &
$ http -b :5000
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2017:14:25:28 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "HTTPie/0.9.2"
get /
$ http -b :5000/blog/2017/4
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2017:14:26:15 +0200] "GET /blog/2017/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 9 "-" "HTTPie/0.9.2"
get /blog
$ http -b POST :5000/blog/2017/4
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Apr/2017:14:26:28 +0200] "POST /blog/2017/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "-" "HTTPie/0.9.2"
post /blog
$ pkill -f plackup
```

After changing the inner PSGI code from a literal anonymous to a coderef, thus:

```
my $get_root = sub { [200, [], ['get /']] };
⋮
        resource '/' => sub {
            GET $get_root;
        };
```

Then the program will not compile anymore:

```
$ perl -c app.psgi
Type of arg 1 to Router::Resource::GET must be block or sub {} (not private variable) at app.psgi line 8, near "$get_root;"
```

The function prototype is [`GET(&)`](https://metacpan.org/source/DWHEELER/Router-Resource-0.21/lib/Router/Resource.pm#L48). When `&` is the first position, it allows the caller to use the abbreviated syntax, sort of like with `sort { … } @list` and `map { … }` instead of `sort sub { … }, @list` etc., see [perlsub#Prototypes](http://p3rl.org/perlsub#Prototypes):

> An `&` requires an anonymous subroutine, which, if passed as the first argument, does not require the `sub` keyword or a subsequent comma.

How can I use coderefs instead literal subs when there is a prototype?

Comment: `&GET($get_root);` perhaps?

Comment: Сухой27, this works, make it a proper answer below so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GET \&$get_root` seems to work.

For a more complicated expression like what you refer to in the comments, you can use

```
GET \&{$get_generic->('get /')}
```

The `\&{...}` operation coerces its contents to a code reference that is suitable to use with a `&` prototype. Likewise, you can use `@{[...]}` and `%{{...}}` in [contexts where you want to workaround a `\@` or `\%` prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022313/168657).

Comment: This does work, have an upvote. Unfortunately, it turns out it's not suitable for me. I'm sorry, my test case was too simplistic. Once you put arguments into the generic function, this fails with `… must be block or sub {} (not reference constructor)`. Code: `my $get_generic = sub { my ($body) = @_; return sub { [200, [], [$body]] }; };` ……… `GET \&$get_generic->('get /');`

Comment: Perfect! I prefer this syntax over disabling prototypes.

Answer (score 4):

Options:

- Bypass the prototype.

  ```
  &GET($get_root)
  ```
- Provide a `BLOCK` as requested by the error message.

  ```
  GET { $get_root->(@_) }
  ```
- Provide a `sub { }` as requested by the error message.

  ```
  GET(sub { $get_root->(@_) })
  ```
- Use something that starts with `\&`. (Undocumented)

  ```
  GET(\&$get_root)
  ```