# how to slice am array ref and return an array ref in one line?

Tags: perl

Consider the following lines of code. I want to slice the array ref $a and return the result as an array ref assigned to $b. I can do that in two lines as shown. I am stumped in my attempts to do this in one line! How can this be done?

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
###the desired result###########################
@b = @{$a}[1 .. @{$a} - 1];
$b = \@b; # $b is [2,3,4,5]
################################################
###trying to get the desired result in one line##
$b = \@{$a}[1 .. @{$a} - 1]; # $b is \5;
$b = \{@{$a}[1 .. @{$a} - 1]}; # $b is \{ 2 => 3, 4 => 5 }
$b = $a->[1 .. @{$a} - 1]; # $b is 1
$b = $a->@[1 .. @{$a} - 1]; # $b is 5
```

Comment: Side note: [avoid using $a and $b specifically](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$a) even as examples, as they are special globals for the sort function - it either bypasses the typo-checking benefits of strict 'vars', or if you declare them lexically, breaks sort calls in that scope. I suggest `$x`/`$y`

Comment: The reason why your attempts are not valid ways to create a reference are because you cannot reference a slice of an array, you must reference a full array. Thus you must create a new array reference, with copies of the sliced elements, as shown in the answers.

Comment: Also, if you want to modify the array in place rather than create a new one, the [splice](https://perldoc.pl/functions/splice) function may be useful (it also works on dereferenced arrayrefs). Just take care that this is really what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can say

```
$b = [ @{$a}[1 .. @{$a} - 1] ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022108/is-there-a-less-clumsy-alternative-for-copying-up-to-n-array-elements/39022313#39022313), there is also

```
$b = [ splice @{[@$a]},1 ]
```

Comment: `splice @{$b = [@$a]}, 0, 1` would create only one copy, as the other solutions do.